# big O that is less than N?

Tags: python, big-o, complexity-theory

Being completely self (and StackOverflow) taught, I'm new to Big-O notation and need to understand it better for some upcoming interviews.

My question is how do you annotate in Big-O when the complexity is less than `N`? Example is a prime calculator that checks for remainder of every integer up to `N/2`, since if we find no divisor less than half, it's certain there will be none in the upper half.

So is that `O(N/2)` or does `N` become `N = N/2` for the purposes of the notation?

```
def primecheck(num):
  i = 2
  while i <= ( num // 2 ):
    if not (num % i):
      return False
    i += 1
  return True
```

Comment: It is still counted as `O(N)`. The constants are discarded. I would highly recommend cracking the coding interview book. It goes through big o, different algorithms and a lot more that you will encounter on interviews.

Comment: Because 1/2 N is a positive constant multiple of N, so O(N/2) **is** O(N)

Comment: you can have things like O(log N) or O(1), which are both less then O(N)

Comment: I think it's important to add that O(N) means "as the number of inputs increase, the algorithm's time increases linearly". This, I think, explains why n/2 is still the same as n - the time still increases linearly with the input increase.

Answer (score 3):

Big-O notation is designed to ignore constant factors. As long as `k` is a constant (meaning, something unrelated to `N`, such as 1/2, 1/3, 1, 2, 3, etc), then `O(kN)` means exactly the same thing as `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

`Big-O` notation is designed to express variable-only complexity, all constants are ignored in this case so `n/2` is expressed same as `4n`. However prime numbers checking is a problem that needs to check only up to `sqrt(n)` so the problem is just `O(sqrt(n))`